# Create a nuget package with a reference to a COM Interop dll

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create a nuget package from a .NetCore Class Librairy. This project has a reference to a COM Interop DLL (Interop.NETWORKLIST). If I run a test project with contains the reference to this project, it works without problems. However, when I build it in a nuget packagee and I add the package to the test project, when I run it, I got an error from the dll which is missing.

After some searches, I found that it is not so easy to build a COM dll in a nuget package and I did some tries.

1. I add manually the COM dll in the nuget package with Nuget Package Explorer :
   [image]

2. I create a .targets file and add it to the project :

- The reference in my csproj :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="EINetwork.targets">
    <PackagePath>build</PackagePath>
    <Pack>true</Pack>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

- The .targets file content :

```
<Target Name="EiNetwork.NETWORKLIST" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <_InteropAssemblyFileName>NETWORKLIST</_InteropAssemblyFileName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition=" '%(FileName)' == '$(_InteropAssemblyFileName)' AND '%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)' == '$(MSBuildThisFileName)' ">
        <EmbedInteropTypes>false</EmbedInteropTypes>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

3. I changed the .nuspec to add the dll manually

```
<files>
  <file src="Interop.NETWORKLIST.dll" target="lib" />
  <file src="EINetwork.targets" target="build"/>
</files>
```

However, with these different changes, the problem stays the same and I cannot use the nuget package in my test project.

Is there something I missed or I did wrong ?

Comment: Try to use `<file src="xxx\Interop.NETWORKLIST.dll(the path of the Interop.NETWORKLIST.dll)" target="lib\netcoreapp3.1" />` in your  `.nuspec` file. Also, before you install this new version of the nuget package, please try to [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) to remove the old unchanged one. Then, delete `bin` and `obj` folder of your main project, then, install the new version of the nuget package.

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "path of the dll" ? the path in the nuget package ? Because the ddl is a dll "generated" by Visual Studio so there is no real path except in the bin folder

Comment: The path of the file on your project folder. actually in the bin folder. It is just a reminder.